# Make function to display running progress and replace line on finish

Tags: shell-script

I would like to display that a installation step is still in progress. So I will add a dot each second to the current line.

Is it possible to make a function for this, so I can add this progress function to every installation step?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Step 1: Apt-get update"
while :;do echo -n .;sleep 1;done &
trap "kill $!" EXIT
sudo apt-get update 2>&1 >/dev/null
kill $! && trap " " EXIT

echo "Step 2: Apt-get upgrade"
sudo apt-get upgrade -y 2>&1 >/dev/null
# Also show progress
```

And if the progress has finished, I would like to replace the current line with

```
Step 1: Apt-get update finished
```

Then the next step will be running...

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep all the progress information on the same line, you can use `\r` for this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Step 1: Apt-get update"
while :;do echo -n .;sleep 1;done &
trap "kill $!" EXIT
sudo apt-get update 2>&1 >/dev/null
kill $! && trap " " EXIT
echo -e "\rStep 1: Apt-get update finished"
```

This displays the periods on the same line as "Step 1...", and then replaces the line with the "finished" message. You might need to add spaces inside the quotes after "finished" to cover all the dots; you might also want to count the dots, and avoid line wrapping (by keeping track of how much you've output compared to `$COLUMNS`).

I highly recommend you log `apt-get`'s output to a file instead of discarding it entirely. Especially in the `upgrade` case, you'll need the output to troubleshoot any errors which might happen...

An easier approach would be to use `apt` instead of `apt-get`: it displays nice progress bars and removes them cleanly when it's finished.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to use this progress display multiple times in my script as there are multiple steps. Is it possible to create a function or something like that?

Comment: For your script I do get the error `example.sh: line 9: 17824 Terminated`